# checking username against database pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The script works to add user data into the db however I want the check if the username is in use but keep running into this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function rowcount() on a non-object in /home/4507408/public_html/registeruser.php on line 78
```

I cant seem to manage to do it with PDO, any help would be great!

```
<?php
                $form = $_POST;
                $username = $form[ 'username' ];
                $password = $form[ 'password' ];
                $firstname = $form[ 'firstname' ];
                $location = $form[ 'location' ];
                $age = $form[ 'age' ];
                $email = $form[ 'email' ];

                $usercheck = $_POST['username'];

                 $check = "SELECT username FROM use WHERE username = '$usercheck'";
                 $query = $DBH->prepare( $check );
                 $query = $DBH->prepare($check);
                 $query->execute();
                 $data = $query->fetchALL();

                 $check2 = $check->rowcount();



                 //if the name exists it gives an error

                 if ($check2 != 0) {

                        die('Sorry, the username '.$_POST['username'].' is already in use.');

                                }

                $sql = "INSERT INTO user ( username, password, firstname, location, age, email ) VALUES ( :username, :password, :firstname, :location, :age, :email )";

                $query = $DBH->prepare( $sql );

                ?>
```

Comment: Not sure but from glancing at the code I have a suspicion you have to replace `$check2 = $check->rowcount();` with either `$check2 = $data->rowcount();` or `$check2 = $query->rowcount();`.

Comment: Why do you use PDO without prepared statements?

Comment: Have you tried  $check2 = $check->rowCount(); It's camel cased. Also, use prepared statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
$check = "SELECT username FROM use WHERE username = '$usercheck'";
```

is wrong. `use` is a SQL reserved word. I assume you meant `user`. It's also a terrible idea to inject a value into the query string with simple variable substitution. The whole point of PDO is to use parametrized queries: https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements